# Floating form on landingpage

Tags: html, css

I need to build a landingpage inspired by this:

[image]

But I cannot figure out how the form is floating over the background? Basically how the div tags are made in this design. Does anybody have a clue about that?

Comment: Yes, you can try with making that div with position;fixed or absolute and setting z-index to make it on top.

Comment: `position:fixed`, `z-index://greater value than other things`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ug8hmrd5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for floating form container

```
     .floatingform {
        position:fixed;
        right:0px;
        z-index:2;
        height:300px;
        width:200px;
        background:green;
        }
```